# How to create a control with ValidationGroup and a custom validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I want to make panels `Visibility` `true` or `false` based on a result of a `Func`.

I have a page with controls as in the following code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server">
        <c:PermissionPanel ID="P1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Val1">
            Validation Group 1 - OK
        </c:PermissionPanel>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>

<c:PermissionPanel ID="P2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Val1">
    Validation Group 1 - OK
</c:PermissionPanel>

<hr />

<c:PermissionPanel ID="P3" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Val2">
    Validation Group 2 - OK
</c:PermissionPanel>

<asp:Panel ID="Panel4" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <c:PermissionPanel ID="P4" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Val2">
            Validation Group 2 - OK
        </c:PermissionPanel>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

In short I have 4 `PermissionPanel` that can be inside other controls.

The code of the `PermissionPanel` is the following:

```
public class PermissionPanel : Panel
{
    public delegate bool OnValidate();
    public event OnValidate Validate;

    public string ValidationGroup { get; set; }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visible = (Validate != null ? Validate() : false);

        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
}
```

I want to get all `PermissionPanel`s from the page and add an event on each accordingly to its group, for example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Magic code here. Linq is very welcome
    // GetPageControls<PermissionPanel>("Val1").AddEvent(() => return true);
    // GetPageControls<PermissionPanel>("Val2").AddEvent(() => return false);
}
```

The code above would make all panels with `ValidationGroup` == `Val1` visible while `Val2` would not be rendered.

**So the questions are**: How can I achieve this? Is there a better way of doing it?

---

In short I want to add a `Func` that will be a validation method allowing the panels to be shown or not. A real example is:

```
// If post owner is the logged user, show controls like edit and delete
() => return (user != null && user.ID == post.UserID);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two ways that I´m aware of: *searching* or *self-registering*. In searching you´ll get every control in the control hierarchy starting by the page, recursively and checking if it is a `PermissionPanel`.

The second way, self-registering which I like you´ll update `PermissionPanel` to register itself in a list inside `Page.Items` and register your validation handler only for controls in this list.

On `PermissionPanel` you can do something like that:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
     base.CreateChildControls();

     List <PermissionPanel> panels;

     if (Page.Items["PermissionPanels"] == null)
         Page.Items["PermissionPanels"] = panels = new List <PermissionPanel>();
     else
         panels = Page.Items["PermissionPanels"] as List <PermissionPanel>;

     panels.Add(this);
}
```

And on page OnPreRender you can iterate over `Page.Items["PermissionPanels"]` and registering validation handlers according to your validation group.

Comment: I guess that's the most efficient way. I've noted that I need to be careful if using inside a `Repeater` or other list control. If I add the event on the `ItemDataBound` I need to check it the current control is parent of a control in my list of controls. But that's it, I've implemented this method. Thank you!